# How to remove stripes between tiles on a grid?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've been working with Unity for six months. I still haven’t found a 100% answer to this question.
**Can you help me?** (I really struggled with this and spent 2 months)
We're talking about these stripes.
[Stripes on Tilemap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tf2rx.jpg)

I'm importing a PNG image. Setting up image properties. I cut it into tiles. I add it to the palette.
I draw with tiles on a grid. And I see these stripes, both in the editor and in the build.

I change the picture settings.
[My picture (tileset) settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZK2VC.jpg)

I'm adding a picture to the atlas. 2D->Sprite Atlas. Here are the atlas settings.
[My atlas settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88Mgh.jpg)

As a result, the stripes disappear both in the editor and in the build, but by **99%**. That is, sometimes, once a minute, a bar flashes on the screen.

I've been testing this issue for 2 months (!). Tested everything. This is not a problem of a specific scene, tile (transparency), size, stacking order, video driver etc.

For now, the solution to this problem is to add to the camera - Pixel Perfect Camera.
But such a decision is not very normal. It limits - it sets the proportions of the camera, adds black bars at some resolutions. Most games do not have such restrictions, some kind of black stripes from the camera and so on. And I want to make games like this. But I can not. I'm literally forced to use Pixel Perfect Camera.

**How to remove stripes between tiles on a grid?** So that I can use a regular camera.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try to adjust the PPUs of your Sprites, and oversize your hexagonal Sprites a little to compensate for the values used in the Transforms.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's the 'point filtering' on the texture, this gives you that precise pixel art look but as a consequence you will need to use a pixel perfect camera to avoid getting these artifacts.  If you change the filtering it should go away. Good luck :)